# Odd over-scroll behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

So we have this website, and when you scroll all the way down to the bottom it keeps scrolling.

I've tried lots of ways to fix this and haven't come across a valid solution.

It seems to be adding margin outside of the main `<html>` tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Only custom JS added:

```
if (document.getElementById("tab1")) {
document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "flex";
document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0].className += " active";
}
var durl = String(document.URL);

if (durl.indexOf("#") != -1) {
durl = durl.substring(durl.indexOf("#") + 1,durl.length);
  openTab(event, durl);
}

function openTab(evt, name) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(name).style.display = "flex";
if (evt == undefined) {
  document.getElementsByClassName(durl)[0].className += " active";
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scroll(0, document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].offsetTop)
  }, 1000);
} else {
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
  }
```

Comment: show us the code, a [mcve]

Comment: Its a paid theme, I cannot lawfully share code. Please just look at the website and you'll see the issue.

Comment: I think its the PageOverlay or PageTransition that is causing some of the issues. I added `height: auto;` and it helped by reducing the amount of white space but the problem was still there

Comment: What's the name of the theme and where did you purchase it?

Comment: Theme is prestige, shopify theme store

Comment: You should be dealing with the company that sold you this theme, not StackOverFlow. Failings of commercial software and systems are their responsibility.

Comment: I've reached out to the theme creators multiple times with no response.

Comment: I think you have two JS files that are clashing with each other. Did you add any new JS files to the existing theme?

Comment: I've added the only custom JS code to the OP, this is for a tabbing system on product pages, but this doesnt affect the home page

Comment: @brooksrelyt I removed both of those divs and same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to the problem:

Any and all images were being applied translate3d and on scroll it was calculating the following:     `transform: translate3d(0px, <insert current scroll position>px, 0px);`

This was causing the page to overflow on itself and was caused by an included libs.min.js package.

What I did to fix this issue was replace `<insert current scroll position>` with 0 where it was being called.

Also a hidden div called .search had transform translateY(-25px) and an ::after pseudo class that had a height of 100vh, removal of this fixed the problem

Thank you all for the help